# Python Remove element from just a list from nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list of lists in Python, such as

```
colours = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

All three lists are the same at the beginning. I want to remove the first 1 from the first list so that I have

```
colours = [['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

but whatever I tried will remove the 1 from every list.

I tried doing `colours[0].remove('1')` but then the result is

```
colour = [['2', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3']]
```

How can I do it?

I have defined colours as:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3']
for i in range(3):
    colours.append(list)
```

Comment: Is that really how you define your list or have you created a list with multiple references to the same list?

Comment: Are you sure about your result ? With your code my output is `[['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]`

Comment: So I have created it like this: ``` list = ['1','2','3'] for i in range(3): colours.append(list)```

Comment: The question is about how you created `colors`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly which is probably what causes your problem.

Comment: @BogdanRotaru Ok first of all using list as a list name is not a good idea because list() is also the function to make lists. Also by appending that list you might have added the SAME list 3 times to the colours list so changing one changes all as they refers to the same object.

Comment: See the duplicate for more detailed explanations. Short answer: do `colors = [['1', '2', '3'] for _ in range(3)]` to create a list of 3 distinct sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code in the comment:

```
colours = []
list = ['1','2','3']
for i in range(3):
    colours.append(list)
```

This is adding the same list 3 times. Therefore when you use:

```
colours[0].remove('1')
```

You are basically removing `1` from the original list. Therefore it is applied across colours as well. This is because all the lists in colours point to the same location in memory.

My suggestion is, first don't use the variable name `list` as it shadows the builtin `list`. Second to build the list you intended, use different lists every iteration:

```
colours = []
for i in range(3):
    colours.append(['1','2','3'])
```

Or using a comprehension:

```
colours = [['1','2','3'] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be running it in a loop somewhere to remove the elements.

colours[0].remove('1') is good.

c = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
c[0].remove('1')
print (c)
[['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']] --output

Comment: As stated in the comments under the question, the problem probably lies in the way the list is created. Your answer doesn't say more than "your code should work" and doesn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange to me, I ran a quick test:

```
colours = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
colours[0].remove('1')
print(colours)   #[['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Update your question with more information if the issue persists